# How do I get port 80 to actually open on AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, putty

I am trying to follow [THIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) tutorial to set up a LAMP on my ec2, with the eventual goal of setting up a WordPress blog on the instance.  I've set the security group as follows: [LINK TO PICTURE OF MY SECURITY GROUP INBOUND RULES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfLf4.png)

I've completed the setup via PuTTY and am SSHing into the instance just fine.  I ran the `chkconfig --list httpd` command, which output `httpd   0:off   1:off   2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off` just like it should, and then I tried entering the public IPV4 address into my browser, it doesn't give me the apache test page, but rather this: [image of port 80 not actually being open, after all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCBUj.png)

I am using the following AMI: amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03.0.20190611-x86_64-ebs

Help!

**EDIT**
var/log/httpd/error.log doesn't exist, so checking it won't help.

Comment: Use a command like `netstat -tan | grep :80` to see if the server is running and listening on `0.0.0.0:80` or `:::80`. That will divide the problem space into two possible problems -- nothing listening on port 80 or something blocking the connection.

Comment: 80 is in red, but it says LISTEN:
`tcp     0    0 :::80          :::*          LISTEN`

Comment: My apache server is up, but I don't understand why, even though the security rules say it's open, port 80 isn't actually open.

Comment: Are you trying to reach the same IP address you SSH into?

Comment: Yessir. I'm clicking the hotlink inside the aws terminal for the public IPV4 address to the ec2.

Comment: I have also tried dropping my computer's firewall - just for a few seconds - to troubleshoot. Still nothing.

Comment: I was able to fix it by installing wordpress in the user data before I started the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding the following to the user data in the instance settings:
 `#!/bin/bash yum -y update yum install httpd php php-mysql -y cd /var/www/html echo "healthy" > healthy.html wget https://wordpress.org/wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz tar -xzf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz cp -r wordpress/* /var/www/html rm -rf wordpress rm -rf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz chmod -R 755 wp-content chown -R apache:apache wp-content wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketforwordpresslab-donotdelete/htaccess.txt mv htaccess.txt .htaccess chkconfig httpd on service httpd start`